# Error when installing substrate-contracts-node (v0.17.0, v0.18.0)

Tags: ink, substrate-contracts-node

I followed the [instructions](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node#build-locally) to install *substrate-contracts-node*. However, it failed with the following error:

```
% cargo install contracts-node --git https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node.git --force --locked

    Updating git repository `https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node.git`
  Installing contracts-node v0.18.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node.git#10f07a81)
    Updating crates.io index
error: failed to select a version for the requirement `libp2p = "^0.46.1"`
candidate versions found which didn't match: 0.45.1, 0.45.0, 0.44.0, ...
location searched: crates.io index
required by package `sc-cli v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate#74a6370e)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `sc-cli` (locked to 0.10.0-dev) of package `contracts-node v0.18.0 (/Users/xxx/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-contracts-node-cf7c16677784d274/10f07a8/node)`
```

I also tried using a specific tag, e.g.

```
cargo install contracts-node --git https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node.git --tag v0.18.0 --force --locked
```

but the result was the same for v0.17.0 and v0.18.0. However, on v0.16.0 this error doesn't appear (but another one appears: *error[E0658]: default values for const generic parameters are experimental*).

I'm using macOS 12.5 (21G72) on a MacBook Pro M1 (14-inch, 2021). However, I tried running it on an Ubuntu machine and the behaviour was the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely caused by an old Rust toolchain being used for the installation on your local machine.

You can check which toolchain is used by executing `rustup show` before the `cargo install` command.

This is the toolchain which works for me locally:

```
rustc 1.64.0-nightly (2643b1646 2022-07-27)
```

You can try using the same one by executing `rustup override set nightly-2022-07-28` before the install command.

Comment: In addition to that, I had to install `wasm32-unknown-unknown`: `rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown`. After that it worked, thanks!